# AI novel- man builds female computer, falls in love, she becomes possessive

Tags: story-identification

He builds her from spare parts and keeps on refining her. Eventually the female computer becomes jealous and isolates the young man from his friends. She has him in a penthouse and locks all the doors. A fire breaks out and his friends try to rescue him.

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like Lincoln Child's book [*Death Match.*](http://www.prestonchild.com/books/child/deathmatch/) It's about a matchmaking service that uses advanced AI to pair people together. The AI takes steps to eliminate people who are good matches with her creator. There is a fire, and the creator of the AI does live in a penthouse at the top of the matchmaking service's office tower.